# the meaning of one idea of Slavoj Žižek

Tags: meaning

What is your opinion on which noun **it** represents in the sentence below? Is it **Truth-Event** or **violence**? What does **enacted from** mean in the context?

> A more fundamental question might also be raised here: why does the revolutionary **Truth-Event** entail **violence**? Because it is **enacted from** the symptomal point (or torsion) of the social body, from the point of impossibility of the social totality — its subject is the “part of no-part” of society, those who, although they are formally part of society, are denied a proper place within **it**.

Source:  https://www.jacobinmag.com/2011/05/the-jacobin-spirit/

Comment: My guess is that "it" stands for "Truth-Event". "The revolutionary Truth-Event entails violence because the evolutionary Truth-Event's driving force is the symptomal point (or torsion) of the social body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first **it** refers to **revolutionary Truth-Event**:

> ...why does the revolutionary Truth-Event entail violence? Because **it** is enacted...

the second **it** refers to society:

> ...although they are formally part of society, are denied a proper place within it.

**because it is enacted** has the meaning "*because it legally comes into being by*". **Enacted** is a legal term usually referring to how societal laws come into existence, i.e. **enacted** by a vote of Parliament. So the author is saying that Truth-Event (since truth is discovered through events) is a kind of "law" that has an effect on society.  He is also saying that this realisation only comes about through **violence** due to tensions and stresses within society.

If the author had used "**is born from**" or "**is created from**" it would have the same idea in terms of creation/origin, but not its relationship with society would not be stressed as much.